# Why is ActionBarSherlock not showing?

Tags: android

I was trying to solve the final Challenge of chapter 18 in this book which is to use ActionBarSherlock , I installed it and everything but When I tried to make it work , when I long press on one of the elements of the list it does select but it doesn't show the action bar options.

this is basically what I did:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        listView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(new com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(
                            com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode mode,
                            com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDestroyActionMode(com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode mode) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateActionMode(
                            com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode mode,
                            com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

                        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                        inflater.inflate(R.menu.crime_list_item_context, menu);

                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onActionItemClicked(
                            com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode mode,
                            com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

                        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_item_delete_crime){

                            CrimeAdapter adapter = (CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter();
                            CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());

                            for(int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--){

                                if(getListView().isItemChecked(i))
                                    crimeLab.DeleteCrime(adapter.getItem(i));

                            }

                            mode.finish();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            return true;

                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

---

Edit:

the above code is called in oncreateView, here's the whole code of the function:

```
@TargetApi(11)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup p , Bundle args){

    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, p, args);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

        if(mSubtitleVisable)
            getSherlockActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);

    }


    ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

        registerForContextMenu(listView);

    }

    //



    //

        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    listView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            getSherlockActivity().startActionMode(new com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode.Callback() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(
                        com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode mode,
                        com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode mode) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(
                        com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode mode,
                        com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

                    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.crime_list_item_context, menu);

                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(
                        com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionMode mode,
                        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

                    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_item_delete_crime){

                        CrimeAdapter adapter = (CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter();
                        CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());

                        for(int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--){

                            if(getListView().isItemChecked(i))
                                crimeLab.DeleteCrime(adapter.getItem(i));

                        }

                        mode.finish();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        return true;

                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    });

    return v;

}
```

the mainifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.criminalintent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
        >
        <activity android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.criminalintent.CrimeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.criminalintent.CrimePagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".CrimeListActivity"/>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I've solved it , it turns out I needed to use setOnItemLongClickListener(listener) instead + setLongClickable(bool)

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ((MyAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

}
protected ListView getListView() {
       if (mListView == null) {
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
       }
       return mListView;
}

protected ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
       ListAdapter adapter = getListView().getAdapter();
       if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
          return ((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
       } else {
          return adapter;
       }
}
```

can work